# Using Python, Azure KeyVault Secret Client connecting programatically

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, azure-keyvault, azure-secrets

> Need a way  to connect to Azure Keyvaluat Secret programatically using
> Python. Found existing doc from Azure which is pointing to usage of
> DefaultAzureCredential from azure.identity. Which explicitly seeks the
> enivironment to set up to have values  [link to git hub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/main/sdk/keyvault/azure-keyvault-secrets/samples/list_operations.py)

[image]

[image]

> Wanted those to be injected manually, instead setting them as Env
> Variable

Answer (score 1):

> One can use the below class from azure.identity i.e **ClientSecretCredential**, find the below code ex: snippet

```
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
from azure.keyvault.secrets import SecretClient

TENANT= <TenantId-in-string>
CLIENT_ID = <ClientId-in-string>
CLIENT_SECRET= <ClientSecret-in-string>
credential = ClientSecretCredential(TENANT,CLIENT_ID,CLIENT_SECRET)
VAULT_URL= <AzureVault-url-in-string>
client = SecretClient(vault_url=VAULT_URL, credential=credential)

print(client)
example_secret = client.get_secret(<secret_name_in_string>)
print(example_secret.value)
```

Comment: That's correct; you can use any credential from the [azure-identity](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/main/sdk/identity/azure-identity) package to authenticate a Key Vault client. You can use the ClientSecretCredential here, but to avoid having secrets in your code it might be preferable to use environment variables or [Managed Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/python/api/azure-identity/azure.identity.managedidentitycredential?view=azure-python).

Comment: Thanks, but I had requirement where, needed these values entered manually instead usage of DefaultAzureCredential. Thought help out others, if the similar requirement comes